# Two-way Databinding with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, android-databinding

I am just learning about `RxJava` in Android and the (supposed) excellent composition of MVVM, databinding and RxJava. Unfortunately I cannot bind an `RxJava` `Observable` directly to a `View`: need a `LiveData`.

So, I was wondering is there a way to implement Two-way databinding with RxJava?

So far I've attempted to write a `BindingAdapter` which adds a listener to the passed `View` and calls `onNext` on the `Subject`.

```
@BindingAdapter("rxText")
public static void bindReactiveText(EditText view, BehaviorSubject<String> text)
{
    view.setText(text.getValue());

    view.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            text.onNext(s.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

What this does is updates the `Subject`/model with any changes in the `View`, so model always has consistent value with the `View`. However, the binding is never triggered for any change in the `Subject` itself (ofcourse we'd have to compare new and old values to stop from looping).

Now, I did try to subscribe to the subject and call `setText` for each emission, but then I'd have to dispose the `Observer`. So what I did was also listened for View Attach State change: subscribe in `onViewAttachedToWindow` and dispose the observer in `onViewDetachedFromWindow`.

```
@BindingAdapter("rxText")
public static void bindReactiveText(EditText editText, BehaviorSubject<String> text)
{
    setText(editText, text.getValue());

    editText.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                text.onNext(s.toString());
            }
        };

        private Disposable disposable;

        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            disposable = text.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .filter(s -> !s.equals(editText.getText().toString()))
                    .subscribe(s -> setText(editText, text.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            disposable.dispose();
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }
    });
}
```

And while that does work in the intended way, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to implement Two-way binding via RxJava.

One of the immediate drawback that comes into mind is, `Activity`/`Fragment` cannot register a for a callback for most android `Views`. For instance, if I use the same approach for a Button and its click, and set up a listener in my `Activity` the binding will stop working.

I am still learning RxJava and its various operators and their uses, so maybe I'm missing something obvious or committing a goof, but I've been trying to working out another way to do this for a few days now, so far have not been able to think of one.

**So my question: What is the best approach to implementing Two-way data binding with RxJava `Observables`.**

Comment: If what you mean is making your `Subject` listen for UI changes, that is NOT possible. And in that case, I think you should fix your understanding about RxJava. Let me ask you: why RxJava categorize the data flow into `upstream` and `downstream`? Why there is always a pair of roles with different terminology in RxJava: `source` and `consumer`, `publisher` and `subscriber`? That's because multi-role doesn't exist in RxJava! You cannot make your `publisher` directly listens for changes made by `subscriber`. That's NOT how Observer Pattern works!

Comment: *`If what you mean is making your Subject listen for UI changes, that is NOT possible.`* Can you elaborate? The first part of the code (without the subscription *to* the subject) does exactly what you say is not possible. Unless I misunderstand you entirely.

Comment: Also I'm not trying to make my `Subject` be *everything* (At least not my intention, do correct me if I'm wrong), however I am subscribing to the subject itself and telling the view to subscribe to the `Subject` to receive any changes/updates in the `Subject`.

Comment: From what I understand about RxBinding: the view is acting as the `source` which emits value every time there is a change to its value. This value change is delivered through `BehaviorSubject`, which acts like a usual Observable. In this case, your `bindReactiveText()` acts as the callback. There is no way you can send updates to the view through updating `BehaviorSubject` (I explained the reason in above comment).

Comment: I think I understand your point, however, isn't the whole point of a Subject to act as an `Observer` and an `Observable`? Also how else would the view update itself to any changes in the model if not by subscribing to the Observable (which is what I'm doing).

Comment: True, but `Subject` acts as an `Observable` only when there is another `Observer` subscribes to it. However, in RxBinding case, our view does not subscribe to that `Subject`. The reason is to avoid circular subscription, which causes infinite loop of assignments (similar to the one introduced here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#infinite-loops). That's we use `notifyPropertyChanged()` to facilitate two-way communication, referring to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208596/discussion-between-abbas-and-harrytmthy).

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to do it like that. While usage of Rx Java with data binding is good(LiveData is better though), your way of implementing it is quite overworked.

This is enough to bind it to the textView.

```
@BindingAdapter("rxText")
public static void bindReactiveText(EditText view, BehaviorSubject<String> text)
{
    view.setText(text.getValue());

    view.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            text.onNext(s.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

To subscribe to it and use it you should use a bit different approach. You should use it in view model that should look like this

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private CompositeDisposable subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
    public BehaviorSubject<String> text = new BehaviorSubject<String>();

    private void bind() {
      subscriptions.add(
        text.subscribe(text -> {
            //do something
        })
      )
    }

    @Override
    public void onCleared(){
      subscriptions.clear()
    }
}
```

and in layout use

```
...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/TextField.Subtitle3.Primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:rxText="@{vm.text}"
    />
...
```

and in fragment

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyViewModel vm;

    public void onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutRes, container, false);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        binding.setVariable(BR.vm, this);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
        vm.bind();
        return binding.root;
    }
}
```

I would do something like this if I would use RxJava for that. I am using LiveData though.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand on the solution you provided.You see, if I don't subscribe to the `Subject` in the `RxBinding` View does not update its values to changes in the `Subject`. Sure first value emitted by the Subject might be shown in the View but not subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

To bind RxJava Observable directly to a View, you need to use [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField):

```
val name = ObservableField<String>()
//ex: name = "john"
```

Then put this in your xml:

```
<data>
     <import type="android.databinding.ObservableField"/>
     <variable 
         name="name" 
         type="ObservableField<String>" />
</data>

<TextView
     android:text="@{name}"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability

**EDIT:**

In case you need to apply it on a model instead of a single field, you can do this:

```
class User : BaseObservable() {

    @get:Bindable
    var firstName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
        }

    @get:Bindable
    var lastName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName)
        }
}
```

`BR` is the name of a class generated by Android Data Binding.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid `notifyPropertyChanged(Br.whatever)` is not something I like.Besides you are missing the question itself a way to implement two-way data binding *using* `RxJava`.

Comment: @Abbas But that is the only way to do Data Binding with RxJava. If you don't like `notifyPropertyChanged`, then consider using ViewModel. Regarding two-way, have you tried `@={name}` instead of `@{name}`?